# Why don't these checkboxes work as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/Cqt5Q/)

1. Click on "jQuery". "latest stable" gets checked
2. Click it again. "latest stable" gets unchecked
3. Click on "latest stable". "jQuery" gets checked
4. Click it again. "jQuery" gets unchecked
5. Click "jQuery"
6. Click "latest stable"; they get out sync

Why? I'm trying to get them to stay in sync (I.e. if any of the sub-checkboxes are checked, the parent should be checked, and vice-versa. Clicking the unchecked parent should check the top child, otherwise if it's already checked, it should uncheck all children). It appears that `checktop.checked` doesn't accurately reflect the UI.

**Edit:** Tested in FF7, Chrome 16, IE9.

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/Cqt5Q/9/) -- This alerts "i'm checked" (if you follow the instructions) when I'd expect it to say "i'm not checked" because you've just unchecked it, and the change event should fire *afterwords*.

Comment: I can reproduce. Strange. My feeling is it has to do with clicking the body but I can't get my head around it.

Comment: @Pekka: You clicked one, then the other? I've been clicking on the labels, not the checkboxes, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Strange. I can also reproduce, and .checked values don't match UI.

Comment: @Mark it lost sync somewhere along the way... I can't pinpoint when exactly. I'm clicking the actual boxes but I don't think that makes a difference.

Comment: @MarkByers: "I'm trying to get them to stay in sync." -- that sentence. Essentially, if any of the sub-checkboxes are checked, the parent should be checked, and vice-versa. Clicking the unchecked parent should check the top child, otherwise if it's already checked, it should uncheck all children.

Comment: It *might* have to do with alternating between clicking the label and the actual box. I somehow manage to destroy the sync that way.

Comment: @Pekka I can reproduce the bug even without alternating between the label and the checkbox, but this could be the issue. Though wouldn't the "change" event make where you clicked moot?

Comment: @Pekka: I don't think that's it. I can reproduce it 100% of the time. Posting an updated fiddle which may illustrate slightly better...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace all occurences of "attr()" with "prop()" http://jsfiddle.net/Cqt5Q/8/

Comment: documentation explains it better http://api.jquery.com/prop/, thanks! didn't know about this function

Comment: although it says `$(elem).attr("checked")(1.6.1+)  "checked" (String) Will change with checkbox state`, and we are running 1.6.1+, so i'm a little confused as to why it isn't actually keeping up with the state....albeit it's returning a string instead of a bool, I suspect it should still evaluate correctly!

Comment: The problem is the setting of "checked" inside the 2nd function. The docs say: *the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set.* ...but the attribute is always set after running the 2nd function , it's been set to true or false and attr() always returns the string "checked", because in HTML the checked-attribute(if present) may only have one legal value: **checked** . So when you use attr() you need to remove the attribute instead of setting it to "false"

Comment: Ahah! That makes sense now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I only notice this happening when:

1. click jQuery
2. unclick latest stable (*at this point*)
3. unclick jQuery

If you use the `prop` function instead of `attr`, it should work accordingly.  I notice that Dr. Molle and I arrived at the same conclusion at almost the same time :)